# How to make a macro function on filemaker pro?

Tags: database, macros, relational-database

I am making a ticketing database using filemaker pro. For the field, number of tickets booked, how do I limit the total number of tickets booked to 40? I am using Filemaker for the first time and I don't know how to use it very well. Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There:

[image: There]

Not sure about "Macro function", but there are a few options to what you are trying to accomplish.  The most the direct:

- Specify the maximum value of your data field under 
  File -> 
  Manage...-> 
  Database...-> (select field) ->Field Options -> Validation.  You can customize the acceptable range of values there.

You can also do a value check upon submission of the record using scripts; this enables you to manage the user experience better.  Within your submission script (aka macro)

```
If [ Requests::nTickets > 40 ]  
Show Custom Dialog [ 
>>>Title: "Limited Number of Tickets"; 
>>>Message: "The number of tickets available for purchase is limited to 40. Please re-enter the amount of tickets you would like to purchase.";
>>>Default Button: “OK”, Commit: “Yes”;
]    
Go to Field [ FTS_Questions::nTickets ]
Exit Script
End If
```

This answer is assuming a recent version of FileMaker (12 or later).